# How does delta update using debdelta-upgrade work?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates, debdelta

A part of message after `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
190 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 830 MB of archives.
After this operation, 12.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I've heard of delta updates, but noticed that Ubuntu does not use it from this piece of information. I also know that you can enable delta updates by installing the package `debdelta` and use `sudo debdelta-upgrade` to install the available delta packages. However, I do not understand where it downloads the delta packages from? Does there exist a repository for the deltas like we have for the regular .deb packages for Ubuntu in `archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool`? How does this method work?

Comment: I don't think that you will get better explanation than [here](https://debdelta.debian.net/html/index.html)

Comment: @mook765 Your suggested [link](https://debdelta.debian.net/html/index.html) does answer my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

debdelta is not part of the core / official packaging system for Debian (or Ubuntu). However, debdelta is developed by a single guy, who is also a volunteer maintainer for some Debian packages.

Looking at the [project page](https://debdelta.debian.net/) it is my understanding that a separate server is needed which computes the deltas. Furthermore it is my understanding the debdelta rebuilds packages to a newer version based on the delta.

As a separate server is needed I believe that debdelta will not work on Ubuntu, as Ubuntu has its own package servers.

Comment: `debdelta` is in the default Debian repos. https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/debdelta

Comment: It's also in the default Ubuntu repos ([link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=debdelta&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)), most likely because universe pulls packages from Debian. However, the presence in a repo doesn't mean anything.

Comment: It means it is "part of the core / official packaging system" Your post makes it sound like you have to get it from a 3rd party repo.

Comment: In Ubuntu it is in "universe". Which is official, but not core. Virtually anybody can suggest and upload packages to universe. It's not related to quality standard in the sense of "guaranteed to work flawless".